# Symbol Rotation with Lines Bulk using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-10.6

[image]I have feature points with specific symbol like square.

Two lines join with 1 symbol square.

I want rotate all symbols along to lines in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

Is there any tool or any option to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the top symbol is the rotation you are looking to match on the remaining symbols. If using ArcMap you can go into the symbol properties, click on the symbol within the table of contents, and enter the desired angle. 
[image: Point Shapefile Symbol Angle]
If you are going for a desired affect, it helps if you know the angle of the line. If you aren't sure, and using ArcMap, ArcMap will display the drawing angle in the bottom left hand corner when you are in an edit session and drawing.

[image: ArcMap Polyline Direction]

Comment: Thanks for answering but i want to Auto rotate all symbols according to Line angle ....any command for auto pick Line angle and adjust Symbol Rotation ?